# Translate Orientation from Sensor data to Geo location

Tags: c#, algorithm, geolocation, navigation, assisted-gps

I am tracking a device that might loose GPS signal then and there. And when the GPS signal is too low, I should use the accelerometer and Gyroscope sensors data to guess which way they should have gone.

I am not doing it in real time. I can store the data and send up for post processing.
So all I want to do is from the point (Lat1, Long1) where we had  a good GPS, I need to find new location (Lat2, Long2) from the sensors data.

I was looking at different algorithms. One of them was inertial Navigational System. I applied Kalman filter and I was able to get to a point to find the Quaternion for each data.

Now can some one help me to translate the orientation data to an actual position? What algorithm or formula should I use? Or is there any program available in C# or in any other language?

Comment: This can be done on the Android Platform Using the 'sensor fusion algorithm cooperative localization' see a demo at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k&feature=player_detailpage#t=1315s